# Titanium Label shows up as Blended Layer in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, titanium

When using the debug option in the iPhone simulator I found that the Titanium Labels show up as Color Blended Layers, even though I set the backgroundColor and explicitly set the opacity to 1. I am hoping that someone here can shed some light why Labels are like that and how I can fix this issue.

```
var pageView = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
});

    var text = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        width: Ti.UI.FILL,
        height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
        top: top+5,
        left: 49,
        right: 10,
        textAlign: "left",
        text: exitCriteria[ix],
        opacity: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
    });
    pageView.add(text);
```

Comment: Sorry, too quick - The versions I use are; Titanium 3.1.2GA Alloy 1.2.1 iOS 6.1.3

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at the Titanium source, it seems that a Label is a TiView containing a UILabel with a clear background.

TiUILabel.m line 147:

```
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

If you want to avoid this behavior, you should either edit this file, or create a module TiUILabel+NoClear that rewrites the -(UILabel*)label; function.

But the first option may remove transparency support for *all* your labels.

Let me know if you need some help with that!

M_

Comment: Thanks for your reply - it looks like you are right. In my case I was thinking that this blended layer would be the cause to the poor performance I see in my app when using the ScrollableView. This may still be the case but I have just discovered that there is a defect raised with Appcelerator relating to the issue I have with the scrollable. So until the Scrollable defect has been fixed I think I will leave this.

Comment: I tried edit the TiUILabel.m in the build file in my project but XCode did not pick it up for recompile (must be trick to force this that I don't know about). Thanks again.

Comment: Make sure you are editing the Titanium SDK, not the file in your project's folder. The SDK is in /Library/Application Support/Titanium/...

And remember to clean your project from Titanium Studio so that the new SDK is installed.